# jadira usertype joda time returns incorrect datetime from database

Tags: jodatime, usertype

I am using jadira usertype for joda time with Hibernate 4. I need to use the jvm date time for storage and retrieval. The problem is that the date read back has an offset of 2 hours. We are on UTC+2. Dates are stored correctly in the database. The database is MySQL 5 .I setup databaseZone and javaZone globally in my session factory configuration as follows:

```
<prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
<prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
<prop key="jadira.usertype.javaZone">jvm</prop>
```

The database itself is configured for timezone SAST. With the above configuration for example a date of 2008-01-01 stored in the database and is read as 2007-12-31T22:00:00.000+02:00. I have also tried this without the global configuration using annotation as follows but with the same results:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime",
parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "jvm"),
         @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "jvm")})
```

If I run the following query on the database,

```
SELECT version( ) , @@time_zone , @@system_time_zone , NOW( ) , UTC_TIMESTAMP( );
```

I get the results:

```
version : 5.5.13
@@time_zone :  SYSTEM
@@system_time_zone  : South Africa Standard Time
NOW() : 2013-04-03 14:33:12
UCT_TIMESTAMP() : 2013-04-03 12:33:12
```

What am I missing here. According to all I understand from the usertype and joda, my configuration is correct.

Comment: It does look like when reading, the database returns UCT, in my case date -2. The setting <prop key="jadira.usertype.javaZone">jvm</prop> is supposed to translate this to the jvm timezone, but this setting seems to have no effect. Unless the jdbc driver does something weird somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve thie issue. It happened due to a bug in the MySQL driver. Here's [a link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15604/)! I upgraded the driver to version mysql-connector-java-6.1.6.  Because I use databaseZone="jvm", I had to force the database to be UTC by using serverTimezone=UTC in the database properties. You also have to use the property setLegacyDatetimeCode=false in order for the bug fix to have an effect

Comment: Most recent version of mysql-connector-java is 5.1.29 as of now. How come you were able to use 6.1.6? And I don't think that bug linked is relevant. It's very old.